# How to edit hosts file in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ip, hosts-file

www.somesite.com can be accessed only through add-ons VPN. 
How can I add it to the hosts file in Windows 10,
so it can be accessed without using a VPN?

The IP address has multiple domain names beside www.somesite.com. 
This happen on all browsers.

Comment: Edit the file as an Administrator.  If you are not an Administrator then the file cannot be modified

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't.  The VPN provides a network path to the destination resource, so assuming this is a machine in a LAN with one of the "non-unique" reserved addresses you need the VPN to even be able to "see" the remote machine.

What you CAN do is make it so you do not have to rely on the VPNs DNS server, so you can continue to use whatever DNS you like and contact the remote machine by name when connected to your VPN (this is what I do with SSH tunnels and a couple of Linux machines that act as gateways on either end).  If this is your goal, then edit the file with plain old Notepad (or Notepad++ or any other PLAIN TEXT editor.  Not Word, WordPad, Write, etc.).  Launch the editor first as Administrator, then use the File-> Open dialog to go get the `hosts` file.

`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Note no extension, so be sure to search for `*.*` and save it that was as well  - `hosts.txt` won't do you any good.

Format is as follows:

```
#first line must be a reference for localhost
#and that should be all that is on that line
127.0.0.1  localhost

# then a local machine name reference
127.0.0.1  my_local_hostname

# then whatever other machine you want

172.16.128.200  my_work_machine_behind_vpn
```

Note you do not need a FQDN or even a valid TLD - but if you DO want to use a FQDN then either use a subdomain of something you actually own OR use one of the TLDs reserved for such use like `.test`  (note that `.dev` and a few other formerly popular internal-type names are now real TLDs ... do not cause yourself headaches in the future!)